# How to manage global variables in C asynchronous programming?

Tags: c, global-variables, vimba-sdk

I'm using Vimba.c API, specifically the AsynchronousGrab example provided in the documentation.

Basically, AsynchronousGrab is a program that asynchronously captures an image. I've customized it to work on a user-sent trigger, which means I have my main code running "on the front", and AsynchronousGrab continuously streaming the camera feed "in the back". Whenever I send a trigger through the `main`, the asynchronous grab captures one frame, processes it, and continue with the streaming.

I already also edited the `AsynchronousGrab.c` to do a custom processing step to the captured frame, and then prints the result on the console.

The generic code from the `program.c` (`main`) is this:

```
        while (1) {
            f̶f̶l̶u̶s̶h̶(̶s̶t̶d̶i̶n̶)̶;̶ 
            printf("\n Insert <c> to capture a frame or <e> to stop acquisition and press ENTER\n\n");
            char_in = getchar();
            if (char_in == 'c') {
                err = VmbFeatureCommandRun(_cameraHandle, "TriggerSoftware");
                if (VmbErrorSuccess == err)
                {
                    printf("Software Trigger sent\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Error: %s\n", ErrorCodeToMessage(err));
                }
            }
            else if (char_in == 'e') {
                printf("Initializing closing routine\n");
                break;
            }
            else {
                printf("Invalid input\n");
            }
            char_in = getchar();    //consumes remaining '\n' from stdin
        }
```

Now, I'd like to update it to allow the image captured (and processed) to be saved.

```
            else if (char_in == 's') {
                /* some code to signal the save*/
                err = VmbFeatureCommandRun(_cameraHandle, "TriggerSoftware");
                if (VmbErrorSuccess == err)
                {
                    printf("Sotware Trigger sent. Frame %d will be saved.\n", frameCounter);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Error: %s\n", ErrorCodeToMessage(err));
                }

            }
```

My problem is, I'm unexperienced with this level of coding, and I cannot understand how do I send a `flag` to conditionally save to another `.c` file.

My first thought was "let's pass a variable by reference". But I don't know exactly how does `VmbFeatureCommandRun()` work. It's not a function from `AsynchronousGrab.c` (the file I edited to add my processing). It's a function from `Vimba.c` library instead. So I would have to edit both the library and the `AsynchronousGrab.c`.

Then I thought about "ok, if not by reference, let's make a global variable". I searched and found about `extern` declarations. Great, but it's an asynchronous program. If the processing of the first capture takes longer, I might be sending another trigger while the first one is still processing, so I might mess up the `flag` value for either of them.
So I thought about having a buffer, i.e., an array of 3 `flags`, but then I should also have a global array of frame identifiers, to match the flag (and the procesing result, and the filename) to each identifier.

Now I'm thinking there might be an easier way of doing this, and I'm over-complicating it, and probably not even considering other factors that wouldn't allow my solution to work.

So, should I be creating two global arrays or not? If yes, do I just declare them as global in `program.c` and `extern` in `AsynchronousGrab.c`? And then find a way of always matching everything, on both sides, through the frame identifier?

Comment: What is `char_in`? Is it a `char` or an `int`. Note that `getchar()` returns an `int`. And `fflush (stdin)` simply invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yikes. I knew you guys were going to trash me for either that or the or the second `getchar()`. The answer is: noone. I was having problems with the `\n` on the buffer, and tried that, didn't work, added the second `getchar()`, worked, never cleaned it.

Comment: @Haris `char_in` is a `char`. The `fflush(stdin)` can (I assume) and will be removed